# How to calculate widget bounds?

Tags: c#, widget, unity-game-engine, bounds, ngui

I need to find the bounds of a widget with all his children. I tried using the following code but got a strange output. Either the widget had children which were more than 100 pixels in width and height the output was something about 1.

```
Vector3 widgetBounds = NGUIMath.CalculateRelativeWidgetBounds(this.transform).size;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
// copied from UIDragObject.UpdateBounds()
public static Bounds GetContentRectBounds(UIRect content, UIPanel uiPanel){
    Matrix4x4 toLocal = uiPanel.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
    Vector3[] corners = content.worldCorners;
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i ){
        corners[i] = toLocal.MultiplyPoint3x4(corners[i]);
    }
    Bounds mBounds = new Bounds(corners[0], Vector3.zero);
    for( int i = 1; i < 4; ++i ){
       mBounds.Encapsulate(corners[i]);
    }
    return mBounds;
}
```

Comment: Like `Encapsulate()` instead `SetMinMax()`, so spectaular. :D